# Cannot call setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock: on AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to override the -HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure: method in AFHTTPClient as shown in the following code:

```c
-(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [super HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:success failure:failure];

  [requestOperation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {

  }];

  return requestOperation;
}
```

When I try to compile it though I get the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPRequestOperation' declares the selector 'setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:'

The setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock: method is defined in AFURLConnectionOperation but AFHTTPRequestOperation is a subclass therefore the method should be available in AFHTTPRequestOperation as well.

I don't have much objective-c experience so maybe I'm doing something silly but I can't find the reason for the compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I had to define

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
```

in the file where I tried to call setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:

I understood that cocoapods already did the #define in Pods-prefix.pch and did not expect that it should be defined again.